# List of folder creation dates in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm so new to this and it's driving me crazy.  I'm trying to get a list of folder creation dates older than 15 years (5475 days) on our file server and export it to Excel.

I've tried a couple of different methods and came across one I thought was working, but it turns out it just throws *all* the folder dates into a .csv file lol I realize this code is probably a disaster, so I'm looking for some help.  Much appreciated :)

```
Function Get-NeglectedFiles {    
    Param([string[]]$path, [int]$numberDays)

    $cutOffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$numberDays)

    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $path
    Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -le $cutOffDate -and { $_.Attributes -eq 'Directory' } }
}

Get-NeglectedFiles -path "S:\Test" -numberDays 2000 |
    Select-Object FullName, CreationTime |
    Export-Csv -Path C:\Scripts\Test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You're missing a "|" between Get-ChildItem and Where-Object. Your filter is never applying because it's nothing to work on. `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $path | Where-Object ...`

Comment: Or you can simplify the command a bit `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $path -Attributes Directory | Where-Object CreationTime -le $cutOffDate`

Comment: Oh...hah.  Thank you for that.  I'll give it a shot.

EDIT: The CreationTime piece is working perfectly!  Thank you.  But it's grabbing all file types, not just directories.  I'll have to try cleaning that part up.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Function Get-NeglectedFiles
{
  Param(
  [string[]]$path,
  [int]$numberDays)

  $cutOffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$numberDays) 
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $path -Attributes Directory | 
  Where-Object CreationTime -le $cutOffDate
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please include a brief explanation along with the code ? It may look obvious to you, but it does not seem to be the same for OP.

Comment: The `$cutOffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$numberDays)` subtracts the desired number of days from current date. 
The `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $path -Attributes Directory` goes thru all subdirectories of `$path` and only returns directories (omits files). The directories are then piped to 
the `Where-Object CreationTime -le $cutOffDate`, which keeps directories that have property `CreationTime` less then the `$cutOffDate`. The result is then implicitly returned from the function. Is that clear?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I tried it and I got an error that said 

"Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Attributes'."

Is it a PowerShell version problem maybe?